# why docker not executing init as lxc

Tags: lxc, init, containers

Docker is not running init. So services are not started during startup. Lxc runs init during lxc-start.Since Docker is using lxc why it is not running init. What are the advantages of not running init and depending on supervisord for daemonization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker is an **application container**, more focused in distribute apps as containers. In this the app/process running **inside** the container is the only one running, their init process. If your process need more apps (mysql, mongodb database, etc.) you don't launch these inside your docker container managed by one init daemon, you launch more docker containers, every one inside the docker container.

You can try http://phusion.github.io/baseimage-docker/ that provides a simple init daemon to run more process inside your docker image (this one is Ubuntu based) or you can try LXD http://www.ubuntu.com/cloud/lxd for container technology used more like a **system container**.

Answer (score 1):

This question has been raised as an [issue](https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/223) on GitHub, and a pull request merged to allow `init` to be run since 0.6.x):

```
docker run $IMAGE /sbin/init
```

[source](https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/223#issuecomment-28887602)

The original reason init wasn't run (not valid since [0.6.x](https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/223#issuecomment-22545359)):

> when starting a new container, docker mint-bounds itself as /sbin/init inside the container, hiding the real /sbin/init and in the proces smaking it unavailable for execution.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19332662/start-full-container-in-docker) may offer more help, and [The Docker Guidebook](http://kencochrane.net/blog/2013/08/the-docker-guidebook/) may come in handy.

Comment: I dont think it is fixed. Iam using 0.7.1 docker. Still facing it. Init says /com/ubuntu/upstart sock not found.

Comment: How are you invoking docker/init?

Comment: docker run ubuntu /sbin/init